# Pros and cons of constexpr class members

Tags: c++, constexpr

Compare these two approaches:

```
// MyClass.hpp
class MyClass
{
  static constexpr char* const FOO = "bar";
};
```

vs

```
// MyClass.hpp
class MyClass
{
  static const char* const FOO;
};

// MyClass.cpp
const char* const MyClass::FOO = "bar";
```

Which one is preferable? I'd imagine that in the second case the "bar" string only gets allocated once, while in the first case it gets allocated once per every .cpp that includes my header. Am I correct? Are there any other points to take into account?

Comment: No, FOO is allocated only once in both cases.There is no reallocation in every included cpp as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version is only possible since `c++17`. It works because all static member variables declared `constexpr` are implicitly [inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

Multiple definitions are allowed (in separate compilation units) but when linked there will be only 1. So your assumption that it gets allocated once in every `.cpp` file is not correct.

Which one is preferable could depend. I would choose the first option if I know I'm not gonna change it ever, or very seldom.

If I need to change it, it could cause all `.cpp` files that `#include` it to have to recompile, and then it would be better to have it separated in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: So what translation unit will it be defined in? The one randomly chosen by the compiler? This asymmetry bothers me... Or will it be outside of all translation units?

Comment: @Valentin It will be defined in several translation units.  From my understanding the linker will assume all the definitions are identical and use one of them. Which one is not specified, you only have the guarantee that once linked it will refer to the same object.

Comment: @super Correct.  Bad things can happen if you lie to the linker.